# How to use real device location in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I'm using Geolocation in my Swift app which all works fine, except I'd like to know how to use my 'real' current location (as opposed to a simulated one). I am using a real device (iPad 2)

Comment: You can't have simulate location on a real device, the location you are receiving is the real location

Comment: When I currently run the app on my physical device it uses the simulated real location, not my real current location

Comment: You can simulate location on a real device via the debug menu in Xcode. If you set it to "don't simulate" then you will get the actual location - note that if you are indoors and unable to receive a gps signal you may not get a valid location.

Comment: Show us your code, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with my device instead. I had to reset my location settings and reboot the device before it would recognise my current location.